# HAProxy - How to raise the log level of responses with status code above 400

Tags: logging, haproxy

Here's my sample configuration:

```
frontend www-http
    bind *:80
    acl status_error status ge 400
    http-response set-log-level err if status_error
    default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
    server backend 127.0.0.1:8080
```

With this config, all responses with status 200 are being logged but 400 and below isn't. If I remove the acl and http-response line, then everything is logged.

I've added those lines to the default config, and I didn't touch any rsyslog configuration. I've tested this in HAProxy 1.5.8 (Debian 8) and 1.6.3 (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: I think this may be a bug.  Judging from [a patch submitted earlier today on the mailing list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/28328), it looks like there may be a fairly subtle error in the configuration parser that results in the log-level being set to "silent" no matter what you supply.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot Yeah, I read that too. So I think I'll just wait for it to be fixed. In the meantime, I used `option log-separate-errors` with `rspdeny . if { status ge 400 }` to transform 4xx errors into a 502 error with log level err.

Answer (score 2):

*(It's four years later, but perhaps still relevant.)*

Using HAProxy 2.2 this approach works for me to have conditional and HTTP-only requests/connection logging on one frontend:

```
global
  # 'notice' level as global minimum (does not include http request logs)
  log /dev/log local0 notice
  [...]

defaults
  log global

frontend myhttpsfrontend
  bind [...]
  mode http

  # enables logging of all HTTP requests at info level
  option httplog

  # raise loglevel from info to notice with status code >= 400
  http-response set-log-level notice if { status ge 400 }
```

I chose to have `notice` level globally, as TCP backends could be very noisy if the global level is `info`. Note that `notice` is a higher severity level than `info` in syslog; that was one part confusing me at first.

The condition `if { status ge 400}` is an inline expression as an example, but you could also use an ACL or some other condition of course.

Relevant basics on HAProxy logging in this blog: [haproxy.com/blog: Introduction to HAProxy Logging](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-logging/).